# Open ViewController from handleWatchKitExtensionRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I faced with such a problem that I can not open my NewsDetailVievController of handleWatchKitExtensionRequest.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {

NSString *counterValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"MY ANSWER %@", counterValue);
NSDictionary *replyDict = @{@"response": counterValue};

reply(replyDict);

NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:counterValue];
NewsDetailViewController *ndvc = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] init];

ndvc.objectId = myNumber;
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:ndvc animated:NO];
}
```

Within this article I load controller for a given objectId and inserted into WebView, when I call the controller can see the empty space in which there is the loaded paper. and a feeling that WebView not boot.

Comment: The watchkit app cannot open its parent app. The parent app will run in the background and handle the request made by watchkit app.

Comment: @RohitKumar i know. I open parent app.

Comment: @RohitKumar that is, I cant run the parent application and open I needed viewcontroller and send back information from apple watch?

Comment: Return in reply block whatever you want to return...